# NSString has weird character that representing for whitespace

Tags: iphone, ios, nsstring, whitespace

I have an array of string in a Plist file that located in resource folder. The string at each index will be a parameter to submit to my server thru POST request. I got error of unrecognized parameter from my server.

Then I NSLog the string out, I saw some weird characters that representing for whitespace. That's the problem.

```
ECELL¬†¬†¬†10100 (U) - Gen (3.0 min, 3.0 hrs)
```

It's supposed to be like this

```
ECELL   10100 (U) - Gen (3.0 min, 3.0 hrs)
```

Thank you for your help.

Comment: How do you create the string?

Comment: I'm using TextWrangler to create my plist file.

Comment: @userXXX that may or may not be relevant. I meant the **code**.

Comment: Which code you talking about?

Comment: @userXXX please stop pretending to be ignorant. The code with which you create the particular NSString instance...

Comment: I think I found problem, because I copied and pasted when I created String for Array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check that whitespaces in your string is actually whitespace character by Command+F and then type "whitespace" in there. If it is not then just simple replace with actual whitespaces.

Answer (score 1):

You should also check the encoding of your string. Which one are you using when creating the plist file ? The NSString instance ? On your server ?
Check that it stays consistent on all places

Comment: Thanks, the problem is I copied string from my web and pasted to create a plist file hold an array. I fixed problem by find/replace all weird character white space with a normal whitespace.